# stack allocation vs reassignment - performance cost

Tags: memory, rust, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

I am writing a single threaded rust program where I need to push elements to a vector periodically. I have below 2 code choice in the processing function:

1. A function that keeps an static object allocated and reassigns it in every processing
2. Function that allocates a new object in the stack in every processing

Given the object type has no dynamically sized elements (it will be allocated in stack), will process1 still have a perf edge over process2 below?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Hash)]
pub struct MyObj {
    mem1: u32,
    mem2: u32,
    // .
    // .
    // .
    mem500: u32,
}

impl MyObj {
    pub const fn default() -> MyObj {
        MyObj {
            mem1: 0,
            mem2: 0,
            // .
            // .
            // .
            mem500: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.mem1 = 0;
        self.mem2 = 0;
        // .
        // .
        // .
        self.mem500 = 0;
    }
}

pub fn process1(vec: &mut Vec<MyObj>) {
    static mut static_obj: MyObj = MyObj::default();

    unsafe {
        static_obj.reset();

        // assign some members of static_obj

        vec.push(static_obj);
    }
}

pub fn process2(vec: &mut Vec<MyObj>) {
    let mut obj = MyObj::default();

    // assign some members of obj

    vec.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Why would you declare a 500-member struct? Why not an array?

Comment: The answer is, profile it! There is no reliable way to get real world performance data by looking at the code. Most likely the compiler is smart enough to compile both to equivalent machine code.